# Jquery mobile script placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two page index.html and login.html. I dont know where should i add my js file.
I have many js files and do not want load all js every time when page changes.
My code is like this:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="indexPage" data-role="page" >
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="indexPage" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Anasayfa</h1>
        <a onClick="logOut()" href="login.html" class="logoffButton" data-role="button" 
    id="logoffButton"  data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" rel="external" ></a> 
      </div>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
$('#indexPage').on('pageshow', function(event) {
    var user = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
    if (user == null) {
        alert("index");
        $.mobile.changePage('login.html');
    }
});
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="loginPage" data-role="page" >
      <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

login.js:

```
$('#loginPage').on('pageshow', function(event) {
    alert("login");  
});
```

My alerts: index, login, index, login. But I want only index and login.
I mean global javascript files should load every time such as codoba.js jquery.js. And index.js login.js should load when page of them loads.

Comment: the placement is correct. Give different pages different ids, `$(document).on('pageshow', '#login, #index', function () { alert('hi') });`

Comment: thanks for your answer. What i'm considering is that: is html going to load js files every time when pages change while 'pageshow' is false?

Comment: i want to increase speed of my app.

Comment: js files will be loaded once as long as the page is in DOM.

Comment: OK,so why i see my alerts: index,login,index,login. Not index,login.

Comment: because `pageshow` fires whenever it occurs. If you want to run code once, use `pageinit`.

Comment: I understant, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the browser is able to cache content as well. If you're using IIS you can config caching specific content to speed up your page by creating web.config files per folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
     </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```